# Image not saved to storage when loading with picasso

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework, synchronization, picasso

I have an application that syncs it's database with a Django server using the Django rest framework. I am able to upload images to the server.

The problem is if an image is uploaded from another device or through the web app directly. When I try to re-sync using the "since" filter it shows that it is calling to GET the image (not made on the current device), but it is never saved. The only way that I found to fix it is to clear android cache and start an initial sync with the server.

I am using Picasso to load images into a new Target:

```
private void saveImage(final String url){
    Picasso.get().load(url).into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            try {
                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File directory = new File(root + "/instrumentImages");
                if (!directory.exists()) {
                    directory.mkdirs();
                }
                String fileName = url.substring( url.lastIndexOf('/')+1, url.length() );
                //String fileNameWithoutExtn = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
                directory = new File(directory, fileName);
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(directory);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch(Exception e){
                Log.v("ActionSync", "Failed to save or load image.");
            }
        }
```

I do not understand why it wouldn't be able to save the image if I am getting the URL. If I do not clear the cache I get an HTTP status of 304.
On the Django test server it shows:
/media/instrument_image/1534360416819.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 305999
as an example.

Answer (score 0):

What about permission? You are trying to save on externalStorage, I had the same problem, It was a permission problem. I recommend first:

```
boolean create = File directory = new File(root + "/instrumentImages");
```

Is it true? If not, you may give you app permission on storage throgh the Settings/Apps&Notifications/YourApp/Permissions in you phone or emulator settings.

Comment: I believe that the directory exists because I am looking at it through the android device monitor. All the images from the initial sync are inside. Also, the app has permission to "modify or delete the contents of your SD card", "read the contents of your SD card"

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem!

The problem is that Picasso holds a weak reference to the target. Before the image is loaded it will be garbage collected.

I fixed the problem using Glide to load images into a SimpleTarget as such:

```
private void saveImage(final String url){
    Glide.with((Context)activity).asBitmap().load(url).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
            try {
                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File directory = new File(root + "/instrumentImages");
                if (!directory.exists()) {
                    directory.mkdirs();
                }
                String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.length());
                //String fileNameWithoutExtn = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
                directory = new File(directory, fileName);
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(directory);
                resource.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("ActionSync", "Failed to save or load image.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {
            super.onLoadFailed(errorDrawable);
            Log.v("ActionSync", "Failed to load image.");
        }
    });
}
```